# Jetpack Compose - Click of button doesn't work each time

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I develop a small-scaled jetpack compose project. I faced an issue with the click of the button.

Furthermore, I've used some base class/function designs for this project. Project uses `BaseViewModel` class and `BaseComposableScreen` composable function to generalize basic communication of view and view-model.

Here is the base things:

```
@Composable
fun <State, Event> BaseComposableScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: BaseViewModel<State, Event>,
    content: @Composable (coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) -> Unit,
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.effect.collect { effect ->
            when (effect) {
                is BasicEffect.NavigateToEffect -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        navController.navigate(effect.route)
                    }
                }
                is BasicEffect.NavigateBackToEffect -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        navController.popBackStack(effect.destination, effect.inclusive)
                    }
                }
                is BasicEffect.NavigateBackEffect -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        navController.popBackStack()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    content(coroutineScope)
}
```

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<State, Event> : ViewModel() {

    private val mutex = Mutex()
    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler(::onError)

    abstract fun provideInitialState(): State

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(provideInitialState())
    val state: StateFlow<State> = _state.asStateFlow()

    private val _effect = Channel<BaseEffect>(Channel.BUFFERED)
    val effect: Flow<BaseEffect> = _effect.receiveAsFlow()

    //optional override
    open fun onEvent(event: Event) {}

    open fun onError(context: CoroutineContext, throwable: Throwable) {

    }

    protected fun emitState(state: State) {
        launchOnMain {
            mutex.withLock {
                _state.emit(state)
            }
        }
    }

    protected fun emitEffect(effect: BaseEffect) {
        launchOnMain {
            _effect.send(effect)
        }
    }

    protected fun <P, R, U : BaseUseCase<P, R>> executeUseCase(
        useCase: U,
        param: P,
        onComplete: ((R) -> Unit)? = null,
    ) {
        launchOnMain {
            val result = useCase.start(param)
            onComplete?.invoke(result)
        }
    }

    protected fun launchOnMain(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
        return viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler, block = block)
    }

    protected fun launchOnIO(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
        return viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler + Dispatchers.IO, block = block)
    }

    protected fun launchOnDefault(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
        return viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler + Dispatchers.Default, block = block)
    }

    protected fun <T> Flow<T>.launchFlow(scope: CoroutineScope = viewModelScope): Job =
        this.catch {
            exceptionHandler.handleException(currentCoroutineContext(), it)
        }.launchIn(scope)

}
```

```
abstract class BaseEffect

sealed class BasicEffect: BaseEffect() {

    data class NavigateToEffect(val route: String) : BaseEffect()

    data class NavigateBackToEffect(
        val destination: String,
        val inclusive: Boolean = false,
    ) : BaseEffect()

    object NavigateBackEffect : BaseEffect()

}
```

I've implemented these base structures for a composable screen and a view model of it. Here they are:

```
class ChurchViewModel : BaseViewModel<Unit, ChurchEvent>() {

    override fun provideInitialState() = Unit

    override fun onEvent(event: ChurchEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is ChurchEvent.PrayToGod -> {
                emitEffect(ChurchEffect.GodListen)
            }
        }
    }

}

sealed class ChurchEffect : BaseEffect() {
    object GodListen : ChurchEffect()
}

sealed class ChurchEvent {
    object PrayToGod : ChurchEvent()
}
```

```
@Composable
fun ChurchScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel = viewModel<ChurchViewModel>()
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.effect.collect { effect ->
            when (effect) {
                ChurchEffect.GodListen -> {
                    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("God listens..")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    BaseComposableScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel) {
        ChurchScreenContent(
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            onPrayToGod = {
                viewModel.onEvent(ChurchEvent.PrayToGod)
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ChurchScreenContent(
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(),
    onPrayToGod: () -> Unit = { },
) {
    Scaffold(scaffoldState = scaffoldState) { paddingValues ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(paddingValues)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        ) {
            Text(text = "Church")
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_location_city_24),
                contentDescription = "Church image",
                modifier = Modifier.size(90.dp),
            )
            Button(onClick = onPrayToGod) {
                Text(text = "Pray to God")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I click the "Pray to God" button. The code that it calls works only odd times. For example, first click works, second time is not. Third click works, forth one not.

I don't know the reason exactly, please, help me to clarify this situation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your coroutine started by `LaunchedEffect` is used to listen for the effects and also showing the snackbar. I assume these operations can block each other, so I recommend you to use the separate coroutine scope to show the snackbar.

```
@Composable
fun ChurchScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel = viewModel<ChurchViewModel>()
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope() // Here is your scope for showing snackbar

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.effect.collect { effect ->
            when (effect) {
                ChurchEffect.GodListen -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch { 
                        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("God listens..") 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```